# Did Rote Antifa post an image of a "Will trade racists for rapists" sign?

Tags: politics, germany

According to [Red Alert Politics](http://redalertpolitics.com/2016/01/29/german-feminist-welcomes-refugees-better-rapists-racists/), this image was posted on the [Rote Antifa Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/Internationalsozialisten):

> [image: Woman carrying sign "Will trade racists for rapists"]

They say the caption translated as "Prefer sexually active fugitive as German racists" (sic). They acknowledge that the original photo was photoshopped *before* being posted, but ascribe the views of the (altered) sign to the entire group.

Was the photo saying "Will Trade Racists for Rapists" posted on the Rote Antifa site?

Answer (score 9):

Maybe. If the post existed, it has since been deleted.

More importantly: The facebook page is not maintained by antifa activists. It has been called [satire](http://www.stern.de/politik/deutschland/-internationalsozialistische-antifa---das-ist-die-facebook-seite--auf-die-sich-die-afd-beruft-7554234.html) and [fake](https://www.vice.com/de/article/zmvabw/mit-diesem-antifa-account-will-die-afd-die-nrw-wahlen-anfechten).

Looking at the posts, it is obvious that they are from far-right activists. It already starts with the name "Internationalsozialisten", which is a play on words, referring to "nationalsozialisten" (ie nazis). The translation of this post is also not quite right. Correctly, it would be "Prefer sexually *hyperactive* refugees to German racists". It is obviously making fun of the issue, and suggesting that refugees are rapists (a right-wing topic, not a left-wing one).

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Yes, technically, it's an antonym. But it's a play on words, no actual anti-fascist group would give themselves a name like that (it's why eg the vice called it unelegant hyperbole). It fits in with the general "satire" of the page, which purports to be an anti-fascist page while spreading far-right propaganda (such as the idea that all refugees are rapists).

Comment: @AndrewGrimm It's difficult to translate plays on words like these (in English, "international socialism" is actually a term that is used; in German, it is not), but it's obviously a reference to nazism. The important part is that it's part of the "satire" as mentioned by vice.

Comment: You'd also avoid a name that gets abbreviated to RAF in Germany.